# IE9 RC just displays blank pages

Tags: internet-explorer

I have just upgraded from IE8 to IE9. When I try and open a web page all I can see is a blank page. If I mouse over the page I can see tooltips so it's almost like the text is white.

I had the same problem with the beta and had to uninstall. I need to test my web app runs OK under IE9 now though so need to get it working.

I am running on a Asus N61J laptop. It has 2 graphics cards - an on board intel and an nvidia geforce gt 325m. A light glows blue when running in power mode with the nvidia or white for the intel.

If I start up IE9 the light changes from blue to white. If I check the use software rendering option the light changes back to blue and the pages appear. I'm guessing IE 9 sees the nvidia, tries to do hardware rendering and the nvidia can't handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a graphics driver issue. I fixed it by updating the nvidia drivers. Windows told me they were up to date but I downloaded newer drivers from the nvidia web site.

One way to test this is to turn off hardware acceleration, restart IE9 and see if the pages appear.

Answer (score 3):

We had this with the x64 bit beta, and had to uninstall all x64 IE versions, then re-install the x32.

Once we completed this, all the pages were showing correctly.

Good Luck