# Embedded video is not shown in Internet Explorer 9 RC or Beta

Tags: windows-7, video, internet, windows-explorer, flash

In IE 9 RC or in beta, the embedded video is not shown in the web page. I verified the security settings in "internet options". Did not find any issue. Please find the screen shot below. I am able to view the flash videos in Youtube. But, for some reason, in some sites the embedded video is not shown.

I don't have this issue with Firefox.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I am able to see view the embedded video in Admin account. But not able to view it in Standard account.

**UPDATE:**

@TomWij, 
Thanks for the suggestions.
The Process Monitor hint helped to nail down the issue. When run with standard privileges, it is getting "ACCESS DENIED" for reading the key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/x-shockwave-flash.
```

When I elevated the privilege to Admin account, it did not have any issue.
Then I uninstalled flash, deleted the registry key and then installed flash again.
Now, I am able to view the embedded video in standard account.

Comment: possible duplicate...http://superuser.com/questions/244204/ie9-rc-just-displays-blank-pages

Comment: I tried the solution of enabling software rendering instead of GPU accelaration. Still I don't see the embedded video.

Comment: Well, it's beta/RC software for a reason

Comment: You've accepted my solution, what step did help you? Also, the bounty is still running, do you need something more or did you forget to assign it?

Comment: Oh, you've updated your answer (please note that this does not inform me so I didn't saw that), nice job on using Process Monitor! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked, it works here so it's a local issue for you.

[image]

---

Let's work from bottom to top:

1. **Reset your Internet Explorer settings**, this should get any odd settings that bug you gone.

   [image]

   I suspect is that embedding is disabled, as in my screenshot above, it is a YouTube video.
2. **Uninstall Java, Flash and Shockwave; then uninstall Internet Explorer. Then reinstall**.
3. **Try different versions from Flash** to check for Compatibility issues.
4. **Disable your Virus Scanner and Firewall** to ensure that they aren't bothering you.
5. As it works as administrator, use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and **filter the Status** on `ACCESS DENIED`.

   This allows you to troubleshoot what key the `iexplore.exe` process can't access.
6. Updating graphics drivers won't work. I'm out of options, **it's a RC**, live with it...

Answer (score 1):

I'd recomend uninstalling flash and reinstalling it.  The flash install is different for FireFox than it is for IE so switching between the two will not give apples to apples comparisons.

I've noticed with the IE9 beta/RC Flash 10.2 works better than 10.1.

Answer (score -1):

The answer above about access to the registry key

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content
>   Type\application/x-shockwave-flash

also works for me. Even easier than above, I just right-clicked on the key in regedit, and allowed all users on the machine read-access to it, and then the embedded videos worked for non-admin users, for example:
   [Shuttle launch seen from airplane window](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2011/02/26/amazing-shuttle-launch-video-from-an-airplane-window)